# How to get Typescript 2 to load all definition files in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

How to get Typescript 2.0.3 to load all definition files in any package installed to node_modules?

I have written a package called somatic, which includes a index.d.ts files, and installed it into a test project. I tried everything to get the definitions to load, messing around with the types and typesRoot options in my tsconfig.json, but to no avail.

This implicit referencing was working a few hours ago, but it suddenly stopped working. I have reinstalled TypeScript 2.0.3 and Visual Studio Code, but the issue still persists.

The only way to have typescript load my definitions file is to add a reference to the top of the test file like so:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/somatic/dist/index.d.ts" />
```

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true
    }
}
```

Comment: That package's `package.json` file contains this setting: `"types": "/dist/somatic.d.ts"`. I would try removing the leading slash.

Comment: I edited the locally installed folder of the somatic package (in node_modules) to remove the leading slash, but the issue is still the same

Comment: "... suddenly stopped working" ... so what was changed just before it stopped working?

Comment: This has happened several times before: I add a new type declaration to a d.ts file, and suddenly all the types are not recognized (there are squiggly lines under them). I remove the type declaration I just added, and the issue still remains. On previous occasions, reinstalling VsCode resolved the issue, but not this time

Answer (score 0):

If you use "node" resolution strategy (which is default I think) then TypeScript searches itself in the node_modules folder. You can read a bit more on that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) with examples of pathes that it uses.

Maybe you need to update TypeScript or your node_modules folder is not placed in a proper place so that it can find it?

Comment: Even if I remove the typeRoots option the behavior is the same, and my node-modules folder is in the standard location on windows.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by standard location on windows, it should be a direct child of any parent of your file if I understand correctly. So e.g. if you have C:\A\B\C\myfile.ts, then node_modules should be in either A, B, or C folders or directly under drive C:. If you use e.g. Visual Studio then node_modules is a folder under a project root and thus accessible to all files under the project root.

Comment: Yes i have the local node_modules under my project folder. And i also have the global node_modules in the standard location on windows

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then. You can try to force the module resolution strategy to "node" but this should be default anyway after some version of TS. Perhaps Visual Studio Code arbitrary changes the current folder that the typescript compiler uses? You can check that if you want by putting the node_modules to the root drive, though that "fix" won't really help so much.